# Sublime Text 3 - Terminal/Browser view

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I've been searching for a plugin for Sublime that would allow me to access a terminal or browser preview in a second column (accessable via <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>), similar to the c9.io interface ([reference](https://a.sinister.ly/kkfjdv.png))